# How Can I make all Data show in the Run Terminal of Pycharm

Tags: python, csv, statistics, pycharm, analytics

am new to learning coding, and I will like to ask these questions:

How Can I make all Data show in the Run Terminal of Pycharm. It gives some ellipses which I dont like, as I want to be able to view all the run data.

Also Hw can I renumber a column, so it will be chronological.

Thanks in anticipation. Attached is a screenshot of my issue. I want to make the column 'Emp ID' chronological.[My Run window of Pycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2sfs.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting row size like this

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', TotalRoW)
```